# Invariant violation: "tesApp" has not been registered

Tags: android, react-native

Invariant Violation: "testApp" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.

I have tried all the solutions provided with similar issue but none has actually worked for me... I cloned the react native project from git and ran the command yarn install to fix and update,  it compiles successfully but wen it starts my android emulator,  it comes up with this error, it's a react native android app I cloned , I have tried deleting the lock files and modules and reinstalling it but still not solving the issue,  please help me out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please destroy your metro bundler and try to run your app again it will work.

Comment: I cleared my metro bundler,  but it generated new error,  error: Unable to resolve module './src/screens/Payment/Payment' from 'App.js'

Comment: This error is basically that bundler is unable to find your file. Check if file exists. If exists than, I usually open that file and press ctrl+s to save file and than it start working.

Comment: thank you , its working now , i started the whole process afresh and started metro bundle and it is working fine

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I tried those solutions plus others I found on-line to no avail.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.